# How to get line and next lines from a text file in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
CHILD:     I saw giraffe swimming in the pool to get that ball.
           Hi everyone!
Teacher:   What is your name. what did you see?
CHILD:     My name is John.I am a boy. I go to school everyday.I have
           two brothers and sisters
Teacher:   I saw giraffe swimming in the pool to get that ball .
```

How Can I get the lines narrated by Child only?

Comment: Have you already tried anything yourself? What if you read line by line, and set a flag whether the child is talking?

Comment: SO isn't a coding service, you need to show us what you are trying and what errors you are getting for us to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("sample.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        if "CHILD:" in line:
            speaker = 1
        elif "Teacher:" in line:
            speaker = 2
        if speaker == 1:
            print(line)
```

That works. next, try posting your approach.